# How do we give users view (only view and no edit) access to Multipass groups?

Tags: palantir-foundry

How do we give users view (only view and no edit) access to Multipass groups? Like where do I click in the Multipass interface?

Answer (score 1):

If you want users to view group memberships within the org you can grant them "View group membership" permissions under the org:

1. Navigate to workspace/settings in the Multipass app > Organizations > Select the Organization.
2. Under Organization details > Organization permissions > Manage > Add user or group that the user is a part of.
3. In the dropdown, select "View group membership"